# Logstash If configuration dropping events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am using the ELK stack to save custom events. The events I am pushing may or may not contain a field called `feed.name`. 
I am using this field to dynamically set the index, so if it doesn't exist I want to set it to `unknown` before sending it to Elastic.

Here is the full config I have:

```
input {
        http{
                host => "XXXXXXXXX"
                port => xxxx
                codec => "json"
        }
}

filter{
        if ![feed.name]{
                mutate { add_field => { "feed.name"=> "unknown" }}
        }
        if [source.asn]{
                mutate { convert => {"source.asn" => "string"}}
        }
        if [destination.asn]{
                mutate { convert => {"destination.asn" => "string"}}
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["xxxxxxxxx:XXXX"]
                index => "l-%{feed.name}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```

Here is my problem: When there is no `feed.name` set, Logstash sets it correctly and everything is fine. However, if the field exists, the event seems to be dropped.

So 2 questions arise here: How is this behaviour explained? And also, how can I make it work (or are there any workarounds)?

Comment: I think you should use `[feed][name]` instead of `[feed.name]`

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work to set the index.

Comment: use `%{[feed][name]}`

Comment: It doesn't work, I should say that feed.name is a field in itself (not a field within a field, if you understand what I mean)